# The slope of the curve having the equation $x^2-2xy+y^2+2x-4=0$

Tags: calculus

Please can anyone help me solve the problem:

> The equation of a curve is given by $x^2-2xy+y^2+2x-4=0$, find slope of the curve at the point $(2, 2)$.

This is new to me. How to find the derivative of this function?

Comment: Tip: Try implicit differentiation and show us what you get.

Comment: The slope of curve at $(2,2)$ means $\frac{dy}{dx}(2,2)$, read about implicit differentiation.

Comment: What do you know?  Have you learned the chain rule and product rule?

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1:

Rewrite your equation as: $y^2 - 2xy = 4-2x-x^2$

Taking the derivative with respect to $x$, we have:

$$2 y y' -2x = -2 -2x$$

Can you take it from here?

Approach 2:

Your equation is a quadratic in $y$. Solve for $y$ and then take the derivative to find the slope.